# when present one view and dismiss that view change navigation bar item position

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When I click on notification button than present notification view controller and dismiss this controller. After this, navigation bar button position get change.

[image]

Comment: you mean, message & notification icons are added to the navigation bar and they get misplaced after another view dismissal?

Comment: @pawan : yes change position

Comment: it's quite not possible if you have added these as bar button items in the navigation bar. they have fixed position in the navigation bar. optionally you can use [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; to reload view, may be that will fix the issue.

Comment: @pawan : its not working ... and same issue i was found in select image from library also

Comment: are you sure you actually placed them inside the navigation bar and didn't place them in another view by mistake?

Comment: barbutton_Notification =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@""     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onPressed_Notification)];
        menuImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"7 Notification"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
         [barbutton_Notification setImage:menuImage];
         NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barbutton_Notification,barbutton_Email, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonArray;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking navigation bar Use a UiView As Custom bar so that you can use it and as Navigation bar has alot of issue regarding customization of the Navigation bar n you can set the navigation bar to none to remove the bar

Answer (score 0):

We'll it didn't should be happening if you're using an UINavigation. My guess to you is to investigate what is causing this behaviour on the navigation - it can be an code you wrote there.

Till there, you can change the buttons position or reset the buttons in this **UIVIewController** method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //put the reset code here or call a method to reset code!
}
```

Are you using a framework to customize the navigation? 
Maybe the problem can be in the framework.